# Out of order race condition

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

When a workflow has a receive activity that occurs after another receive activity and the second receive activity is called first the workflow holds the caller by blocking for 1 minute before timing out.

I want the workflow to return immediately when there are no matching workflow instances.

I do not want to change the timeout on the client as some calls may take a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in WF4, at least I am not aware of it being fixed yet.

Comment: Thanks does make it a bit strange making clients know about the workflow though

Comment: The client shouldn't know about the workflow internals. However the expected order of messages is not an internal thing. After all you can't pay for an order and then add more items to it before it ships. The thing is WSDL doesn't provide for a way to describe message order.